# Personal Finance App Monthly Reports Database Design ( SQLite )

Tags: database-design, mobile-reports

I am building a personal finance mobile app that supposed to generate monthly reports, now I have a problem, confused about how to design the database to be monthly, I need the wallet to get archived after a month from the day it's created and transfer the remains/loss to the new wallet ( next month ) if exist.

[image]

Now my idea is to generate one wallet with xx money and let the user change the start date and make the mobile app automatically generate a new wallet every month on that day with the necessary transactions like there a loss/remain from the old wallet, and archive or prevent the user to make any transaction to the old wallets.

**does my logic make sense or ...?** ( Note I'm still learning and this my first app using SQL/Database so please be patient with me )

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm understanding you need to design a database which will be record transactions of a user and draw some conclusion like a profit/loss at the end of a month. To achieve this you don't necessarily need to create a wallet every month this is just basic accounting. You will need `Transaction` table and `Transaction_History_Log` and `Charts_Of_Accounts` for more detail check [this](https://www.accountingcoach.com/chart-of-accounts/explanation). Your `Transaction` table will have a `one-to-many` relationship to your `Transaction_History_Log` and `Transaction_History_Log` will have `many-to-one` with your `Charts_Of_Accounts`. So just basically you will need to record journal entries [this](https://www.freshbooks.com/hub/accounting/journal-entry#:%7E:text=A%20journal%20entry%20is%20a,step%20in%20the%20accounting%20cycle.) will help you get a more understanding about what journal entries are in accounting. You can set a `createDate` attribute in your `Transaction_History_Log` to just get the a snapshot of month or a whole year or whatever the user likes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you show me a diagram for this on https://drow.io, also I need the user to put his budget for the month so I guess it's necessary, and mostly you got it right I want to make a finance app that collects user expenses/income for the month and sum/subtract with his entered budget. my problem is I need to reset this budget every month and move the loss/profit from old to new after resetting if there any.

Comment: Sorry I have been really busy these  previous days so was unable to reply. This is the diagram of what I was talking about [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5faK.png . Basically I'm just creating a `User` table which will hold a `budget` attribute that will determine the `User` budget and `isActive` attribute will determine if the user is actively using their current budget of the month. The `CreateDate` attribute will help me determine `from and to date` of the spendings he did and my `transaction_details` will do double entries such as `debit` and `credit` for any kind of transaction...

Comment: ... to fully understand this design you first need to study accounting and `Chart of accounts` hold which account is being `debited ` and which is being `credited` that's all. This is just a rough idea you can make this design much more efficient and better just play around with it hopefully this helps.

Comment: @heshamshawky just tagging